# Ignoring Specific Warning in SublimeLinter3 (flake8 addon)

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, flake8

How do you ignore a specific warning in SublimeLinter3 (specifically flake8 addon)?

The documentation only mentions how to add rules to ignore all warnings of a certain type. However, I want to be able to consider each warning case-by-case and disable warnings based on whether I think it needs to be fixed.

For instance an import like

```
from nose.tools import *
```

will cause a warning mentioning that the linter is unable to verify whether undefined names are able to be used.

In this specific case, I don't want there to be a linter warning in this file, but possibly in another file, I want this same warning to show.

Does SublimeLinter currently support this functionality (This is similar to a right-click "ignore warning" functionality in other IDEs) ?

Reference:

https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3

https://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

From the [flake8 README](http://flake8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/violations.html), try this to ignore the line:

```py
from nose.tools import *  # noqa
```

Comment: Actually that disable the flake8 checks for all the whole file, but it should only ignore this line in checks. So this is a bug in SublimeLinter.